# Custom Toolbar changes the color of Statusbar

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I'm implementing my own toolbar/actionbar however, the statusbar color goes to brown, and I'm trying to give it the dafaults, which is a dark blue. How can I changed this. I've trying playing around with style.xml theme, also the toolbar theme. but I can't get it right. any help appreciated.
styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    tools:context="com.example.com.mytoolbar.MainActivity" />
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.com.mytoolbar.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try removing popupTheme from toolbar.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code of Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"               <!-- Check this line --> 
    android:theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle"                 <!-- Custom theme added -->  
    android:elevation="4dp" 
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    tools:context="com.example.com.mytoolbar.MainActivity" />
```

Removed `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

If you use `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` Toolbar will get default `colorPrimary` from Base Application Theme.

To, change text and overflow icon color, Add this custom theme to style.xml and apply to the Toolbar:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, but now my text and overflow icon are in black. How can I change them to theme defaults.. white! Thanks for the help

Comment: that's nice.. an all white theme! great

Comment: If the answer helped you can upvote and accept the answer, you know ;)